# Логин форма в C# с использованием SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать логин форму? Вот к примеру, у меня в Базе не один, а много пользователей... и как проверять, что пользователь ввел в прогу? Чтобы прога определяла, что я вошёл именно в аккаунт с логином `admin` и паролем `admin`, и чтобы прога при успешном входе считывала данные именно пользователя с логинов `admin`, а не другого какого-нибудь? Извините, но я реально не могу правильно сформулировать вопрос. Но тема осталась "Как сделать форму входа?"

**UPDATE**

И вообще, объясните, как она работает и что происходит, когда пользователь нажимает "Войти".

Answer (score 2):

```
select login from users where login = 'логин' and password = 'пароль'
```

И приятно, и правильно. А на клиенте проверка на NULL.

Answer (score 0):

1 января, день офигенных вопросов =)
Значит, ты ввел логин и пароль, запрос с этими данными обратился в БД и проверил, если ты такая пара (логин-пароль) в базе, если да - предоставляются юзеру права, если нет - выводится какое-то предупреждающие сообщение.

Comment: А как делать эту проверку?

Comment: Учите sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users where login = 'логин' and password = 'пароль'
```

Если вернуло 1 строку, то данные правильные. Если 0, то неправильные.

Comment: select NULL from users where login = 'логин' and password = 'пароль'
будет правильней, кажется, да и траффику приятней) Мелочь, а приятно

Comment: select NULL from users where login = 'логин' and password = 'пароль' будет правильней, кажется, да и траффику приятней) Мелочь, а приятно

Сами поняли что написали?

Comment: я то - точно

Comment: Симпатишней и логичней было бы: select count(*) ...